# Linked list is not displaying as it should

Tags: c, linked-list

I am currently working on a problem for my C programming class and am having a bit of an issue with my program. I have managed to get the program to compile but the display function is not actually displaying the contents of the list as it should. Here is my code:

```
/**
 * Create a structure that has one variable called value and one pointer to the list (making it a
 * linked list). Prompt for 5 values from the keyboard as input and store them in the linked list. Print
 * out the current contents of the list. Allow the user to add one more value to the linked list, and
 * print the contents of the list again.
 */

#include <stdio.h>

struct ValueStore
{
    char value[100];
    struct ValueStore *nextItem;
};
typedef struct ValueStore ValueStore;

void display(ValueStore *);

int main()
{
    printf("This program will ask you for five words or phrases and store them in a list before repeating those integers back to you.\n");
    printf("You will then be able to add a final value (for a total of six) before the program repeats the list back to you and finishes.\n");

    /**
     * Initialize the first five structs in the list.
     */
    char inChar1[100];
    char inChar2[100];
    char inChar3[100];
    char inChar4[100];
    char inChar5[100];
    printf("Please enter a word or phrase: ");
    gets(inChar1);
    printf("Please enter a word or phrase: ");
    gets(inChar2);
    printf("Please enter a word or phrase: ");
    gets(inChar3);
    printf("Please enter a word or phrase: ");
    gets(inChar4);
    printf("Please enter a word or phrase: ");
    gets(inChar5);
    ValueStore fifth = { inChar5 };
    ValueStore fourth = { inChar4, &fifth };
    ValueStore third = { inChar3, &fourth };
    ValueStore second = { inChar2, &third };
    ValueStore first = { inChar1, &second };

    display(&first); //print out the list starting at first

    /*
     * add final item to list
     */
    char inChar6[100];
    printf("Please enter a word or phrase: ");
    gets(inChar6);
    ValueStore sixth = { inChar6 };
    fifth.nextItem = &sixth; //link fifth and sixth together

    display(&first);
}

void display(ValueStore *listStart)
{
    while(listStart)
    {
        printf("%s\n", listStart->value);
        listStart = listStart->nextItem;
    }
}
```

When I attempt to run the program and enter "hello", "world", "what", "is", and "up" to answer the prompts my display function outputs a single line of `�p` and goes onto the next input. I input the last string (say "hello") and I again get `�p` in the terminal.

I know that gets() is deprecated in favor of fgets() but my instructions are explicitly to use gets() so my hands are tied there.

My gcc compiler is fully up to date

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 5.2.1-22ubuntu2' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-5/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,java,go,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-5 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-libmpx --enable-plugin --with-system-zlib --disable-browser-plugin --enable-java-awt=gtk --enable-gtk-cairo --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-5-amd64/jre --enable-java-home --with-jvm-root-dir=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-5-amd64 --with-jvm-jar-dir=/usr/lib/jvm-exports/java-1.5.0-gcj-5-amd64 --with-arch-directory=amd64 --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/eclipse-ecj.jar --enable-objc-gc --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 5.2.1 20151010 (Ubuntu 5.2.1-22ubuntu2)
```

Comment: Can I get an example output?

Comment: Do not use `gets()` use `fgets()` instead.

Comment: I'm baffled how you got it to compile.

Comment: Your intialisation of the `ValueStore` variables are not correct. You cannot copy arrays by assignment. One fix is to change `char value[100];` to `char *value;` That is, store a pointer to the buffer. Another approach is to do a `strncpy` from the local buffer into the `ValueStore` `value` buffer. The preferred method will depend on what else you want your program to do with those nodes.

Comment: kaylum I would totally mark you answer as correct if I could.  Thanks for the help!  You fixed my problem and a heck of a lot of warnings to boot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, compiler gave you lot of indications (aka warnings) about the issue in the code:

```
test41.c: In function ‘main’:
test41.c:35: warning: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast
test41.c:36: warning: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast
test41.c:36: warning: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast
test41.c:37: warning: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast
test41.c:37: warning: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast
test41.c:38: warning: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast
test41.c:38: warning: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast
test41.c:39: warning: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast
test41.c:39: warning: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast
test41.c:49: warning: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast
```

However, this code change will work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct ValueStore
{
    char value[100];
    struct ValueStore *nextItem;
};
typedef struct ValueStore ValueStore;

void display(ValueStore *);

int main()
{
    printf("This program will ask you for five words or phrases and store them in a list before repeating those integers back to you.\n");
    printf("You will then be able to add a final value (for a total of six) before the program repeats the list back to you and finishes.\n");

    /**
     * Initialize the first five structs in the list.
     */
    char inChar1[100];
    char inChar2[100];
    char inChar3[100];
    char inChar4[100];
    char inChar5[100];
    printf("Please enter a word or phrase: ");
    gets(inChar1);
    printf("Please enter a word or phrase: ");
    gets(inChar2);
    printf("Please enter a word or phrase: ");
    gets(inChar3);
    printf("Please enter a word or phrase: ");
    gets(inChar4);
    printf("Please enter a word or phrase: ");
    gets(inChar5);
    ValueStore fifth;
    strcpy(fifth.value, inChar5 );
    fifth.nextItem = NULL;

    ValueStore fourth;
    strcpy(fourth.value, inChar4);
    fourth.nextItem =  &fifth;

    ValueStore third;
    strcpy(third.value, inChar3);
    third.nextItem =  &fourth;
    ValueStore second;
    strcpy(second.value, inChar2);
    second.nextItem =  &third;

    ValueStore first;
    strcpy(first.value, inChar1);
    first.nextItem =  &second;


    display(&first); //print out the list starting at first

    /*
     * add final item to list
     */
    char inChar6[100];
    printf("Please enter a word or phrase: ");
    gets(inChar6);
    ValueStore sixth;
    strcpy(sixth.value, inChar6);
    sixth.nextItem = NULL;
    fifth.nextItem = &sixth; //link fifth and sixth together

    display(&first);
}

void display(ValueStore *listStart)
{
    while(listStart)
    {
        printf("%s\n", listStart->value);
        listStart = listStart->nextItem;
    }
}
```

OUTPUT: As per your question.

```
./a.out
This program will ask you for five words or phrases and store them in a list before repeating those integers back to you.
You will then be able to add a final value (for a total of six) before the program repeats the list back to you and finishes.
Please enter a word or phrase: hello
Please enter a word or phrase: world
Please enter a word or phrase: what
Please enter a word or phrase: is
Please enter a word or phrase: up
hello
world
what
is
up
Please enter a word or phrase: to
hello
world
what
is
up
to
```

Comment: Since this is the only actual answer posted, I am going to accept it.  Kaylum did help me get this solved however.